# PHPExcel reading xls file, get cell styling (font-weight, color, etc)

Tags: styles, phpexcel

I am trying to read an excel file and render it as a html table. I would like to get the style that has been applied in excel to a cell and render it in html as well. For example, some cells may have text in BOLD, how do I get that information and use it in the most efficient way?

This is the code I have so far (I am trying out PHPExcel the first time so I am eager to hear any comments or improvements I can make to this):

```
if ($_GET["xls"]) {

require_once("classes/PHPExcel.php");

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load( dirname(__FILE__) . "/demo.xls" );
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Sheet1')->toArray(null,true,true,true);
?>
    <?php if ( count($sheetData) < 0) : ?>
        <table class="table striped">
            <?php foreach( $sheetData as $y => $row ) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php foreach ( $row as $x => $cell) : ?>
                        <?php if ( $x === "A" ) : ?>
                            <th><?php echo $cell; ?></th>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <td><?php echo $cell; ?></td>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?> 
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a look at PHPExcel's existing HTML Writer: that already handles merged cells, cell formatting (including borders), font styles, etc.

Comment: I would but I need to add custom classes to the table tag and as far as I see, HTML Writer does not allow me to do it.

Comment: The existing HTML Writer doesn't allow you to set custom classes, but it does everything else for you... either use the existing HTML Writer as the base for your own code, and add the custom class stuff yourself (that's still 90% of the work already done for you), or look at the existing HTML Writer class aand see how that retrieves its information about cell styles so that you can use the same methods

Comment: Ah yes, there's a point. I will see if I can extend the class and do my custom stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following code works:

```
$objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Sheet1')->getStyle("B13")->getFont()->getBold()
```